# How do I use my keyfile to sftp transfer data from one server to another

Tags: unix, authentication, ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp

I cant scp, the other server only takes sftp connections.

Currently, I am trying to do

```
sftp jay@server.name.com:/files> put -r ~/
```

`-i keyname` does not work, just resolves with `illegal option -- i`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try:

```
sftp -o "IdentityFile=keyname" jay@server.name.com
```

You can use `-o` to pass any option that's valid in `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Nailed it. thanks! how do i keep it there normally?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "keep it there normally". If you mean that you want the `IdentityFile` option to always automatically be given, check out [UtahJarhead](http://superuser.com/users/127831/utahjarhead)'s answer about putting it in `~/.ssh/config`

Answer (score 8):

Copy your PUBLIC key to the server using traditional means.

On server:

- Create `.ssh` if it doesn't exist:

```
[[ ! -d "${HOME}/.ssh" ]] && mkdir -p "${HOME}/.ssh"
```

- Implement the public key:

```
cat /path/to/public_key.pub >> "${HOME}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

- Set appropriate permissions.  OpenSSH is VERY ANAL about the permissions of the files in question:

```
chmod go-rwx "${HOME}" "${HOME}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

After that, you should be able to log in from the client using the PRIVATE key.  To automate a transfer, you want to use a batch file, which is just a text file containing a list of commands to execute.

```
echo "put filename.foo /safe/path/filename.foo" >> /tmp/batchfile.txt
sftp -b /tmp/batchfile.txt -oIdentityFile=/path/to/private_key user@host
```

Alternatively, feel free to create a ~/.ssh/config file in ssh_config format so you can just type this in the future:

```
sftp -b /tmp/batchfile.txt host
```

Sample contents of `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host the_hostname
    User user_name
    IdentityFile /path/to/private_key
```

Comment: Ill try this on the next batch, the solution above did the trick though.

Answer (score 1):

I got into this issue recently and what worked for me in my macbook default terminal setup is the following

```
sftp -i ./privateFilePath.key username@url.com
```

Note you might be promoted with **UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!** message in which case you need to run this command to make sure your private key is not accessible by others.

```
chmod 600 privateFilePath.key
```

In some cases you need to put **sudo** in front of the command, this is only if you are working in a admin protected directory

I wish thats helpful :)

Comment: Why do you expect this to be helpful when the question said that the `-i` option is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to setup sftp on ec2, [this article](http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/setting-up-an-sftp-site-on-amazon-web-services-ec2-creating-an-account-to-share-with-a-third-party-and-restricting-that-account-to-allow-only-sftp/) might help

Comment: Sorry, it really didnt.

Comment: This "answer" has nothing to contribute to the question. Worse, it is just a link to a page that will someday disappear.

Comment: Well wouldn't you know it, it did disappear, for anyone caring to find out what the article was, take a look here. https://web.archive.org/web/20150107025158/https://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/setting-up-an-sftp-site-on-amazon-web-services-ec2-creating-an-account-to-share-with-a-third-party-and-restricting-that-account-to-allow-only-sftp/